# Extracting EXIF info from ImageProxy

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to extract all the available EXIF data from ImageProxy object.
I can get the rotation information using
`imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()`

But the TagBundle object seems to be empty

```
TagBundle tagBundle = imageProxy.getImageInfo().getTagBundle();
tagBundle.listKeys() -> empty
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for this too. I have got average YUV for an ImageProxy and I want to convert it to absolute exposure.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is still a hassle if the goal is getting all the set EXIF tags, but this at least allows you to get them by tag name.

```kotlin
fun proxyToExif(proxy: ImageProxy): ExifInterface {
    val bb = proxy.planes[0].buffer
    val buffer = ByteArray(bb.remaining())
    bb.get(buffer)
    return ExifInterface(ByteArrayInputStream(buffer))
}
```

For example, to get the exposure time:

```kotlin
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME)
```

All the set tags are defined internally but not exposed, which is unfortunate.
[image: List of set exif attribute keys]